# Yeoman Generators in SVN

Tags: git, svn, yeoman

I'm currently building a yeoman-generator for my company. We want to use it for future projects. And we pretty much use SVN wherever it's possible.

Opposed to git a subversion working copy has .svn folders in all its subdirectories. And there's my problem. When I use the directory-method of my generator to copy a directory it will copy all .svn folders too. And then SVN is getting confused.

Is there a way to exclude all .svn dirs but still to copy the .htaccess files?
I don't want to copy all files for themselves. There are a couple of them.

And are there maybe other problems with SVN+Yeoman I didn't even encounter yet?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer! :)

**SOLVED:** Using SVN 1.7+ with my SVN client fixed the issue. Since that version there is just one .svn directory in the root.

Comment: Can't you just upgrade Subversion?

Comment: OH, didn't know they changed that to a single .svn-folder. I'll have to ask our svn-guy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Subversion **repository** doesn't have `.svn` subfolders, it's Working Copy of repository
2. Best method of "cleanup" WC from *any amount* SVN-related metadata (for *any SVN version*) is using [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) (you can also export any tree directly from repository, without intermediate WC)

Comment: 1. Sorry, my bad. I fixed it.

Comment: 2. I would rather keep it under subversion control.

Comment: @user3734681 - What is "it"? Results of yeoman processing of tree?